# making clean url with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make clean url with htaccess
I have a profile.php page and I get user domain name to display his page
now if the user for example hit www.XXXX.com/domain I will display his main page

it is equivalent to www.XXXX.com/profile.php?id=domain without htaccess file
I used this code and its working very fine

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(SCRIPT_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond %(SCRIPT_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/$ ./profile.php?id=$1
```

now I am trying to get page id and the view that the user wants to display but it didn't work

note page id and view are optional values , if didn't found in the url I will display the main page

I want the url to look like www.XXXX.com/domain/pageid/view ,
which is equivalent to www.XXXX.com/profile.php?id=domain&pid=pageid&v=view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %(SCRIPT_FILENAME) !-d
RewriteCond %(SCRIPT_FILENAME) !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)\/(\w+)\/(\w+)\/?$ ./profile.php?id=$1&pid=$2&v=$3
```

Comment: thank you but I found in the pages when I pass the page id and thw view that the CSS and images have different url like this
http://XXX.com/butterfly/paged/4/style.css
can you help me fix it ?

Comment: @AymanJitan just link to the full path of the css like `"//XXX.com/style.css"` (`//` is protocol agnostic)