# Clean URLS with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm making a website, and I have a profile view thingy that looks like this:

```
localhost:8080/profile?username=ImSchnebz
```

But I want it to look like this:

```
localhost:8080/profile/ImSchnebz
```

I've been searching everywhere, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13680295/how-to-rewrite-url-in-php-using-htaccess-file-what-change-in-php-code

Comment: You searched everywhere? There's a [ga](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804992/making-clean-url-with-htaccess?rq=1)-[zi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11484255/mod-rewrite-for-clean-url?rq=1)-[ll](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21234831/creating-clean-urls-using-htaccess?rq=1)-ion questions like that here on SO.

Comment: @LinusKleen I've tried those too, I just get 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You'd get an answer similar to those from the existing questions which in turn would lead to a server error. So the real question is, why are there HTTP 500 errors. Right?

Comment: @LinusKleen Basically yeah

Comment: The close this question and ask the right question [in the right place](http://serverfault.com/).